# Should there be a featured tab in search results?

Tags: feature-request

I asked [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178795/reduce-a-number-range-to-the-shortest-possible-root) a while ago, and since it didn't get much attention I added a bounty.  However, when I search by the r tag, there is no featured header, as can be found on stack overflow site when searching a tag:

[image]

Vs:

[image]

Is this intentional?  I can't imagine that many people search bounties across all questions, more they will search a tag, then notice that there are open bounties, and give those questions additional attention.

In the current state the benefit of offering a bounty would seem to be reduced, is there a reason for this?

It seems that the tag 'r' was not recognised as a tag, as when I type [r] I get the featured column. Should the search bar recognise r immediately as a tag?

Comment: This seems to be by design. In any case it's network-wide mechanics, applicable to all Stack Exchange sites. Should I migrate this question over to Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm not sure that it is network wide, tryping r in the stack overflow search bar returns results for the tag

Comment: Notice how the SO search bar is auto-correcting your search to be `[r]`. It wouldn't make sense for the search engine to be site-specific - the Code Review search bar does the same auto-correction if you type `C#`. Could be related to the number of posts in that tag, I don't know what the specifics are. In any case [here is the help center content for the *advanced search* feature](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: @Mat'sMug fair play, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

Searching '[r](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=r)', searches for just the letter r. If you want the tag you have to surround it in [], and so r would be [r]. [Searching for this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=newest) does come up with a featured tab, [which contains your question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r?sort=featured).

Even without this feature, featured is still good, as there's a [list of all featured questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured). With this feature it gets better as you can also filter by multiple tags, such as [`[c] [performance]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c+performance?sort=featured), which comes up with a question with a bounty, where [`[c] [beginner]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c+beginner?sort=featured) doesn't. Where a C person might follow both C and C++, and search [`[c] or [c++]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b?sort=featured).

It does however seem like you cannot access the featured tab if you search by text. For example searching "[Reduce a number range to the shortest possible root](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Reduce+a+number+range+to+the+shortest+possible+root&sort=featured)" doesn't come up with a featured tab. Neither does "[[r] Reduce a number range to the shortest possible root](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+Reduce+a+number+range+to+the+shortest+possible+root&sort=featured)".

I don't know if this is intended, however I can't see a great benefit to wanting to search via text for featured questions, as it's likely that the question will be tagged with something you're interested in.